# Guideline for defining modules in Jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss6.x

is there any guideline for defining modules in **JBoss AS 7/6.2 EAP** ?

e.g

Is it wrong if we define a module like

```
jboss/modules/systems/layers/base/com/myproj/lib/main/
```

instead of

```
jboss/modules/com/myproj/main/
```

since in jboss the class/jar loading happens through defined module.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put your modules under the system layer. It will work, but the correct way is to put it directly under modules.

More information about the topic:

- Chapter **[Configuring Modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-Configuring_Modules.html)** in the EAP Administration Guide
- Sample of **[installing a JDBC driver as a core module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html)** in the Administration Guide
- Article about the **[Layered Distributions and Module Path Organization](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LayeredDistributionsAndModulePathOrganization)** in the EAP & Wildfly